# iOS Accept incoming call via public API

Tags: ios, system-calls

I want to accept the incoming calls via public API in iOS. I know it can be solved via private API. I have read the document about Core Telephony and CallKit. I think it is for show information about calls , not for controlling. And I think CallKit works for VOIP?
 I just want to accept the incoming calls which is not VOIP and hang up it via public API. Could it be possible? Thanks in advance.